# How to fix the any present error in the SQL Query?

Tags: mysql, sql, nested, subquery

I'm trying to test some queries on my Database Design provided by my University. I'm trying to combine the queries by testing and getting the result individually but unfortunately there's some error. I need to figure out what kind of error is there and how to fix it.

Create a query that displays each country with three calculated columns
showing total number of swimmers and how many Gold, Silver and Bronze
medals were won. Sort by number of Gold medals won.

```
SELECT Country, COUNT( ViewTeams.MemberID ) as Members
FROM ViewTeams
GROUP BY Country
order by Country

Select SUM(CountGold)
from MEDAL, ViewTeams
where MEDAL.MemberID = ViewTeams.MemberID
group by ViewTeams.Country
```

These are working great but I need more output to get mine.

```
SELECT Country, COUNT( ViewTeams.MemberID ) as Members,
       (Select SUM(CountGold) from MEDAL, ViewTeams where MEDAL.MemberID = ViewTeams.MemberID group by ViewTeams.Country)
FROM ViewTeams
GROUP BY Country 
order by Country
```

This is what I'm trying to get and the result output should have the Country Name, Count which is the Number of Players in the team of each Country and Gold Count which is sum of Gold of each player in one team. In my case, I've GoldCOunt of individual player but I don't know how to get gold count of people in one country team.

Comment: Try SELECT vt.COUNTRY, SUM(m.CountGold), COUNT(vt.MemberID) FROM ViewTeams tv, MEDAL m WHERE m.MemberID = vt.MemberID GROUP BY vt.Country ORDER BY vt.Country

Comment: Hi, I think  you need to indicate/know the connections between the tables

Comment: Thanks, I actually used joins to fix this issue and it's working like a charm